# Currency format only working for one dynamic EditText and not for the others

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

The following `for` loop adds `x` amount of rows depending on the size of items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < shoppingQuantityAndItems.size(); i++) {
    TableRow label = new TableRow(this);

    EditText quantity = new EditText(this);
    quantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    quantity.setText(shoppingQuantityAndItems.get(i).get(0));
    System.out.println("Size: "
            + shoppingQuantityAndItems.get(i).get(0));
    label.addView(quantity);

    TextView items = new TextView(this);
    items.setText(shoppingQuantityAndItems.get(i).get(1));
    System.out.println("Item: "
            + shoppingQuantityAndItems.get(i).get(1));
    label.addView(items);

    price = new EditText(this);
    price.setId(i);
    price.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    price.setText("");
    label.addView(price);
    updatePrice(price.getId());

    CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
    ch.setChecked(false);
    label.addView(ch);

    table.addView(label);
}
```

Because I want each different price `EditText` field to have different values when the user inputs them, I call a method with their unique ID:

```
public void updatePrice(int id){
    updatedPrice = (EditText) price.findViewById(id);
    updatedPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        private String current = "";

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
                updatedPrice.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[£,.]", "");
                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);           
                String formated = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
                        .format((parsed/100));          
                current = formated;
                updatedPrice.setText(formated);
                updatedPrice.setSelection(formated.length());
                updatedPrice.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
```

I was just wondering if anyone could tell me how to make sure when I input a number into any of these text fields, then only that value changes, and not the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong `EditText` widget.

`updatedPrice` presumably is a data member of your class. This is not a good idea, as you do not have just one of these `EditText` widgets.

Moreover, your `onTextChanged()` assumes that `updatedPrice` will be pointing at the right `EditText` widget -- the one the user happens to be typing into -- and statistically that is unlikely.

Assuming that the rest of the code is actually what you want, then you need to change:

```
updatedPrice = (EditText) price.findViewById(id);
```

to be:

```
final EditText updatedPrice = (EditText) price.findViewById(id);
```

This will cause your `TextWatcher` anonymous inner class to use the `updatedPrice` you retrieve at the time of the `updatePrice()` call, not some random `EditText` that you have in a data member of the class.

Or, you could have the `TextWatcher` do the `findViewById()` itself. Either way should work.

I would recommend just getting rid of the `updatedPrice` data member and fix up the rest of your code, as you may have other similar sorts of bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your help.In removing updatedPrice would I be making anything final? And how would I make the TextWatcher do the findViewById()?

Comment: @jonathaninnes: "In removing updatedPrice would I be making anything final?" -- if you follow my first suggestion, you are making a *local variable* named `updatedPrice` and have that be `final`. "And how would I make the TextWatcher do the findViewById()?" -- add a call to `findViewById()` in your `onTextChanged()` method. You would need to make the `int id` be `final int id` in your method parameter.